# Python и Sqlite. Вывести Русские символы

Tags: python, sqlite

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема при работе с Python и SQLite. Вот код, в котором я создаю столбцы, заполняю данными, а потом пытаюсь эти данные вывести.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')    
c = conn.cursor()
conn.execute("create table if not exists person(firstname, spots)")          
data = [(u"Иван", 10), (u"Марья", 20)]                                       
conn.executemany("insert into person(firstname, spots) values (?, ?)",data)  
conn.commit()

c.execute('select * from person order by firstname') 
while True: 
    tmp=c.fetchone() 
    if tmp: 
        print repr(tmp)
        print tmp
    else: 
        break
```

Но на выводе получаю что-то типа этого:

```
(u'\u041c\u0430\u0440\u044c\u044f')
```

Как решить проблему? Буду благодарен.
P.S. Ubuntu Linux, Python 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас идет вывод на Юникоде: `\u041c=М`, `\u0430=а`, а консоль ваша очевидно не понимает Юникод.

Надо либо вывод транслировать в KOI-8 на котором работает большинство консолей либо найти консоль понимающую Юникод.

Comment: я лично брал консоль, которая точно понимает юникод `rxvt-unicode` - с вторым питоном ничего не получается, третий работает в любой консоли (системная локаль у меня юникодная).

Comment: Юникод, юникоду рознь. UTF-8, UTF-16 - может в этом дело?

Comment: в консоле точно utf8 (если быть точным - `uk_UA.utf8`). 
Я конечно много чего ещё не знаю,  но не до такой же степени:).

Comment: Может text_factroy?